# angularjs, existing javascript object shows null, how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a situation where when i console.log a object it shows to be null but in the same time to have some properties in it.

I'm fallowing up [this tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/wBhtRLWHIR/6-authenticating-users-with-a-service) or in short:

```
.factory('Auth', function ($http, $q, $firebase, FBURL, $location, $firebaseSimpleLogin, $rootScope) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
        var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
        console.log(auth);
        var Auth = {
            signedIn: function () {
                return auth.user !== null;
            },
            login: function (user) {
                return auth.$login('password', user);
            }
        };

        $rootScope.signedIn = function () {
            return Auth.signedIn();
        };

        return Auth;
    });
```

and i get this:

[image]

in this case, after authenticating,  `console.log(Auth.signedIn());` return `false` because the object in the log shows as null, but when i open to look inside i can see the properties

what is this?

Comment: Is this process async? The user object is probably loaded by the time you go look at it in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`$AngularFire.$fireBaseSimpleLogin.login`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasesimplelogin-login-provider-options) function returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Meaning its asynchronous. Patrick Evan's comment is accurate. By the time you look at the object in the console, it now has information in it.

If you continue to follow the tutorial, towards the end the controller will wrap a `login` function to properly handle the promise.

**Note:** this is also why the `Auth.login` function that you've written simply returns the value of another function call. You're essentially creating an interface to abstract the login implementation details away from the controller (or other services) later. The controller doesn't really need to know what service you're using to login with, just that the `login` function returns a promise that it can do something with later.